# How can we know that changing variables to conjugate momenta is possible?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am reviewing the derivation of Hamiltonian mechanics from Lagrangian mechanics, but I simply cannot understand how we can 'change variables' from $\dot q$ to $p$.

Even on a very simple level, how can we know that the relation:

$$p = \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot q}}(q,\dot{q},t)$$

is bijective between $\dot q$ and $p$?

Further, once we have reached the realm of Hamiltonian mechanics, we declare that the 'state' of the system is determined by $(q,p)$. But if we know $H(q,p,t)$, we can perform a Legendre transform to get $L(q,\dot q, t)$ and then use the above relation to determine $p(t)$. In other words, mathematically speaking once we know $q(t)$, we can determine $p(t)$ directly, so surely we are using too much information in using *both* $q(t)$ and $p(t)$ to describe the state of the system?

I have reviewed textbooks at length, but the most that I can find is that Goldstein refutes such claims as 'being entirely against the spirit of Hamiltonian Mechanics', and I have found difficulty in converting this into a mathematically precise argument.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, OP is right. The relation $p_j=\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}$ might not be invertible wrt. the velocities $\dot{q}$, i.e. the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) might be singular, which leads to [primary constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint). However, in case of a singular Legendre transformation, by performing a so-called Dirac-Bergmann analysis (which may lead to secondary constraints), it is still possible in principle to define a corresponding Hamiltonian formulation. For details, see e.g. Refs. 1 & 2.

References:

1. P.A.M. Dirac, *Lectures on QM,* 1964.
2. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.